# How to run tests in Laravel in parallel, while excluding some tests?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

Both
`php artisan test --parallel`

and

`php artisan test --exclude someGroup` (this excludes tests which are annotated with someGroup)

work, but

`php artisan test --parallel --exclude someGroup`

doesn't

I saw

[image]

However I can't think of a reason why these 2 couldn't be combined, so does somebody have a solution to this problem perhaps?

> The "--exclude" option does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the option name is different under [paratest](https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest/blob/80f74c95adb8d8ebe67f1c7245abb0a4a0da7880/test/Unit/Runners/PHPUnit/OptionsTest.php#L286):

```
php artisan test --parallel --exclude-group=someGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's artisan [does not support --exclude](https://artisan.page/#test) when running tests. It has been asked previously and the developers [struggled to understand](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/is-there-a-way-to-run-tests-in-parallel-with-filters) a use case.

You do have the option of [using Paratest](https://laravel-news.com/tips-to-speed-up-phpunit-tests).

Comment: ? Artisan has supported `--exclude` for a long time, as shown by the question itself, and the question itself also acknowledges Paratest. Your Laracasts link is about running a single test in parallel and doesn't contain anyone at all (let alone developers) discussing artisan's `--exclude` switch. This is not remotely an answer to this question.